# 500 - Unknown column

Tags: joomla, php

После неудачного обновления с Joomla 2.5 на 3.3 появилась эта ошибка:

```
500 - Unknown column 'a.mask' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT a.id, a.asset_id, a.title, a.alias, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.fulltext, CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN a.state ELSE 0 END AS state, a.mask, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, CASE WHEN a.modified = 0 THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.version, a.parentid, a.ordering, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.metadata, a.featured, a.language, a.xreference,c.title AS category_title, c.alias AS category_alias, c.access AS category_access,u.name AS author,( SELECT MAX(contact.id) AS id FROM eoio_contact_details AS contact WHERE contact.published = 1 AND contact.user_id = a.created_by) as contactid,parent.title as parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route, parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0) AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count FROM eoio_content AS a LEFT JOIN eoio_categories AS c on c.id = a.catid LEFT JOIN eoio_users AS u on u.id = a.created_by LEFT JOIN eoio_categories as parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id LEFT JOIN eoio_content_rating AS v ON a.id = v.content_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT cat.id as id FROM eoio_categories AS cat JOIN eoio_categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' AND parent.published <= 0 GROUP BY cat.id) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id WHERE a.id = 3 AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2015-02-24 20:25:11') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2015-02-24 20:25:11') AND (a.state = 1 OR a.state =2)
```

Кто может подсказать, где это исправить?
Откат назад не помог. Спасибо.

Comment: @juliyaya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Каким образом правили? Можно поподробней. У меня та же проблема.

Answer (score 1):

[[@juliyaya](/users/31624/juliyaya)](/users/31624/juliyaya), в сущности `eoio_content` (`"a"` - это её псевдоним/алиас) отсутствует атрибут `mask`. Даже если Вы добавите этот атрибут, возможно, выявится ошибка в другом запросе (деградация).

[Здесь вот пишут, что исправить нельзя](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=769733). Так что правка ручками неизбежна.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. База данных криво стала. Исправили.